# Sending commands from TextWrangler (BBEdit) to the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, applescript, bbedit

I want to send commands from TextWrangler (or BBEdit) to the terminal. Even if [I found this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/pasting-commands-from-textwrangler-to-terminal-applescript-troubleshooting), I don't understand how that works since I'm brand new to Unix and running Applescripts.

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    set the_selection to (selection of front window as string)
    if (the_selection) is "" then
        set the_selection to line (get startLine of selection) of front window as string
    end if
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    do script with command the_selection in window 1
end tell
```

I saved an Applescript that looks like this:
[image]

Now, what I think is to put the script in the TextWrangler Scripts Folder:
[image]

1. But then, how do I send commands to the Terminal.app?
2. How can I press cmd + enter to send a line from TextWrangler to the Terminal?

Comment: I want to run my file line by line. If I want to record all of what I'm doing to test different functions without running the whole script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the script in the `"/Users/yourName/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Scripts"` folder

After that:

- Open the preferences of the TextWrangler
- Select "Menus & ShortCuts" --> "Scripts" --> "your script" to add
  your shortcut to the script
- TextWrangler accept the (cmd + enter) keys as shortcut
  [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I guess we can now use autocompletion in some way... I going to find out. Thanks!

Comment: @jackjr300, What application did you process that Preferences image in to add the arrows, particularly the curved arrow?

Comment: @user3439894, I use the `Preview` application on **El Capitan**, menu "**Tools**" --> "**Annotate**" --> "**Arrow**".`- ` Then drag one of the blue handles to move the arrow or resize it, drag the green handle to make a curve.`- ` You can change the shape style, you can add text at the beginning or at the end of the arrow.

Comment: @jackjr300, Thanks for the info on the image annotation. Also thanks for the tip on assigning command-enter from TextWrangler Preferences. I had tried assigning in the Apple's System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts and on OS X 10.8.5 and while I can technically assign command-enter for the script menu command in TextWrangler nonetheless it doesn't work.  It deletes what's selected and inserts a newline, which of course defeats the purpose. However when doing it from TextWrangler Preferences it works.  So thanks for everything. +1

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an AppleScript *script* in TextWrangler's Script menu, it (or a link to it) must be in TextWrangler's Script folder located at, *~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Scripts* in order for it to appear on the menu. Note: The "~" in that path is your Home Folder and the Library folder may not be visible. You can open it from TextWrangler's Script menu, Open Scripts Folder command and place the *script* or link to the *script* from wherever you saved it.

For the purpose of answering this question I created an AppleScript named **Run Selected Line(s) in Terminal.scpt** and placed it in TextWrangler's Script folder and is now available on the Script menu in TextWrangle as show in the image below.

[image: TW_Script_Menu.png]

That said, the script you have, as written may fail as Terminal can be a bit finicky. In other words, if Terminal is closed when executing the *script*, then the *code* as written can produce an error, e.g.: "A scripting error has occurred: Terminal got an error: Can’t get window 1."

Even telling Terminal to activate didn't open a window like it does when opening Terminal from the Dock Tile I have set to "Keep in Dock" and I'd get the aforementioned error. So a Google query yielded much useful information. So I experimented with a few different solutions I saw and the *code* I'm using is shown below.

---

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    activate
    set the_selection to (selection of front window as string)
    if (the_selection) is "" then
        set the_selection to line (get startLine of selection) of front window as string
    end if
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    -- delay 0.5
    do script with command the_selection in front window
end tell
```

---

Note that I've commented out the `delay` *command* with `--` and may or may not be needed depending on if Terminal is initially  closed and or how slow your system responds. The *value* is in *seconds* expressed decimally. You can uncomment and modify if/as necessary.

Image of *code* showing syntactical highlighting:

[image: code showing syntactical highlighting]

Note: This was tested under OS X 10.8.5 and TextWrangler v4.5.9 (3390) and may react differently in other versions of OS X and or TextWrangler.